# NancyFx - Web Service Initiator

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, webserver, nancy

We are interested in creating an Web Service initiator which consumes files FTPd to a Windows directory, processes to JSon or SOAP and, finally routes the resulting document to a Web Service.

We implemented a Web Service (NancyFx) Listener and it works quite well. However, for Nancy Web Services to initiate an HTTP response programmatically, I am not sure where to start.

Any advise, direction would be greatly appreciated.

Very best,

Tim

Comment: What do you mean by initiating an HTTP response? Do you mean a request?

Comment: I suspect you are correct.  A request.  We have a file which contains data decorated in XML and were asked to load it to a SOAP service.  Perhaps I should have framed the question differently; I am not familiar with Web frameworks.  I selected NancyFX to route messages between a source a target system. It works well for this purpose. The requirement has changed - the source and the target are reversed...  the source uses SOAP.  I don't actually know where to go from here.  I would entertain any via option (including Winforms).